# How to unpack c struct in python 3.2?

Tags: python, c, sockets, struct, python-3.x

I'm working on a server (implemented in Python) client (implemented in C) application.
I want to unpack raw bytes received from a C client using struct module at server side (Python).

My C structure (from C client):

```
typedef struct lokesh{
    int command;

     union 
     {
        struct{
            int data[100];
            int ttl[100];
        };

        struct{
            char config[256];

        };   
     };
} mystructdata;
```

Unpacking at server side (Python):-

```
import struct

data,address=socket.recvfrom(1024)
result=struct.unpack('<i 2048s',data)
print(result[0])
```

But I'm getting an error :-

```
struct.error: unpack require object of size 2052
```

I think problem is in my unpack method's format string `'<i 2048s'` argument.

Edit :-

> now, i have replaced format string `'<i 2048s'` with format string
>   `'<i 256s'`

Comment: Why wasn't any kind of (at least semi-) standardized communication format appropriate for your problem? There is Google's Protocol Buffers for one - that is quite efficient, and has libraries for a lot of languages...

Comment: my control is at server side only.. i.e unpacking/decoding  and can't do anything at client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lokesh, I'm not a python expert, but it looks to me like you're telling python's **struct** that you have:

- a little-endian integer, followed by
- 2048 char[]

(based on http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)

Looking at your C struct definition, that's not what you have at all.  You have:

- an integer, followed by one of:

  - two integer arrays of 100 elements each
  - one char array of 256 elements

Now, without looking at the C code which pushes the struct onto the wire, it's difficult to know about the endianness of integers (network byte order is big-endian).  But that aside, your data specification to **struct** looks wrong.

I'm guessing that the interpretation of the union in the C struct will depend on the contents of **command**.  As such, it seems like you'll need to examine **command** first off, then come up with an appropriate format string for **struct** based on that.  Note that in the data/ttl case you may trip over struct padding issues since it's possible that the compiler on the client side may decide to insert some padding between the **data** and **ttl** arrays in order to satisfy alignment requirements, etc.

Comment: sir, i think you are right that command contents will decide union struct selection. but, i want to know i'm using correct format string expressions.... if(command==union_1_selection) then : format_string= '<i ii' else if (command==union_2_selection) then : format_string='<i 256s'

Comment: ..i solved my above problem, actually problem was with my formating string argument of unpack method, i replaced it with :---> `struct.unpack("<i 800s",data)` , since union size will be:- 2( 100x4) = 800s

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

- [`.recvfrom()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) returns a tuple of `(data, address)`, you need to pass just the data to `struct.unpack()`.
- You are reading only up to 1024 bytes from the socket, but the unpack format wants 2052 bytes. Read from the socket until you have received enough data first.

Comment: sir yes, i have corrected 1st point now. but on specifying 2052 bytes i'm getting error :--> struct.error: unpack require object of size 2056

Comment: @LokeshKumar: I did not say that your struct pattern should be adjusted. A `i` integer is 4 bytes, and you want 2048 characters, each 1 byte. Total size 2052 bytes, so you need to pass `unpack` 2052 `data` bytes.